# Notification is not shown on Android 8

Tags: java, android, android-8.0-oreo

I need to make to show a notificaction on Android but I can not find the right solution to do it. It seems everything perfect.

**XML of main Class** (just ImageButton):
**

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.35"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.695"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />
```

**

**Initialise button:**

```
private void addelement(){
notify = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.notification);
}
```

**Notification() method:**

```
public void notification (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, notification.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setTicker("Hearty365")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle("Default notification")
            .setContentText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentInfo("Info");


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());
}
```

I call my **notifiction() method on an ImageButton**

```
notify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                notification(view);
            }  
        });
```

Now this is my **notification activity:**

```
public class notification extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
    }
}
```

And my **notification XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp.notification">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Info on the notification"
            android:id="@+id/Texto"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have debug the project, and it get stuck on **this**:

```
public boolean performClick() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
```

**Main LogCat error:**

```
07-28 11:17:08.595 1487-2742/? E/NotificationService: No Channel found for pkg=com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp, channelId=null, opPkg=com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp, callingUid=10084, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10084, notification=Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=default defaults=0x1 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
```

This is **my LogCat** when running and trying to perfom the method:

```
07-28 11:13:45.062 7553-7553/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-28 11:13:45.122 7553-7553/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
07-28 11:13:45.779 7553-7553/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-28 11:13:46.576 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
07-28 11:13:46.695 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-28 11:13:46.695 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
07-28 11:13:46.695 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-28 11:13:46.695 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
07-28 11:13:46.705 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa39fd3c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
07-28 11:13:46.755 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa39fd3c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa4bf2d40)
07-28 11:13:46.803 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp W/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0::Mapper: getService: found null hwbinder interface
07-28 11:13:46.847 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /system/lib/hw/gralloc.ranchu.so from the current namespace instead.
07-28 11:13:46.972 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa39fd3c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa4bf2d40)
07-28 11:13:48.891 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=19KB, data=25KB
07-28 11:13:48.939 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=19KB, data=26KB
07-28 11:13:48.939 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
07-28 11:13:48.945 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=19KB, data=43KB
07-28 11:13:48.946 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=19KB, data=43KB
07-28 11:13:48.946 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
07-28 11:13:48.947 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: JIT allocated 72KB for compiled code of void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
07-28 11:13:48.947 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
07-28 11:13:49.098 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=100KB, data=60KB
07-28 11:13:49.101 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=97KB, data=45KB
07-28 11:13:49.891 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=125KB, data=57KB
07-28 11:13:49.896 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=121KB, data=56KB
07-28 11:13:49.896 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
07-28 11:13:50.904 7553-7598/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa39fd3c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa4bf2d40)
07-28 11:13:56.008 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=240KB, data=163KB
07-28 11:13:56.009 7553-7558/com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=162KB, data=113KB
```

Thanks

Comment: notification.class is an actiivty..?

Comment: Can you show us your activity? Wehre and when do you call your notification() method? Does LogCat show any exceptions or messages?

Comment: I will edit to show notification activity right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with following code, it works:

```
public void showNotification(Context context, String title, String message) {
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, notification.class);
        notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context, 0,
                new Intent[]{notifyIntent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

Comment: Make it sure this function is called or not? show some Logs or Toast in first line of this function

Comment: The function is being called by an ImageButton. I will post the LogCat right now :)

Comment: This is the LogCat error `07-28 11:17:08.595 1487-2742/? E/NotificationService: No Channel found for pkg=com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp, channelId=null, opPkg=com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp, callingUid=10084, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10084, notification=Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=default defaults=0x1 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)`

Comment: your device version? I think google play services are not available on that. Update it and then try. There is no issue in code

Comment: Emulator Nexus_5X_API_ Android 8.0.0, API 26

Comment: Since it is an emulator, how can I procees with this update? Thanks in advance

Comment: But i have checked and It has GOogle Play services on that

Comment: if it has then it should be having the updated version as you are using API 26, the latest till date.  Try the same code on some other device , it would work there

Comment: I will try to generate the apk and test it on my phone

Comment: Oh God! Thanks a lot Usman! I really appreciate your help. It worked on the phone

Comment: 'happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Since API 26 (Android 8.0) you need to register and set a [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels) in order to show a notification.

1. Register a NotificationChannel e.g. in your MainActivity:

   ```
   // Register NotificationChannels needed for API 26+ to display notification messages
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
       NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(
               Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       NotificationChannel infoChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_INFO,
               getString(R.string.notification_channel_name_info), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
       infoChannel.setDescription(getString(R.string.notification_channel_description_info));
       infoChannel.enableLights(false);
       infoChannel.enableVibration(false);
       mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(infoChannel);
   }
   ```
2. Define a NotificationChannel for your Notification:

   ```
   Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
           (...)
           .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_INFO)
           .build();
   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   notificationManager.notify(CAPTURING_ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

From the Android 8 [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-channels.html):

> Android O introduces notification channels to provide a unified system
>   to help users manage notifications. When you target Android O, you
>   must implement one or more notification channels to display
>   notifications to your users. If you don't target Android O, your apps
>   behave the same as they do on Android 7.0 when running on Android O
>   devices.

So, follow the above link on documentation and find out how to (1) create a notification channel and (2) use the channel while showing the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Your **activity name** and **method name** are same. rename any one. 
let's rename method like this,

**showMyNotification method:**

```
public void showMyNotification (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, notification.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = P
```

And make call from notification(YourActivity) like this,

```
notify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showMyNotification(view);
            }  
        });
```

Notification is showing up!

Comment: when debuggin states an error, which I have writed on the body of this question :)

Comment: Why do you use the performClick () method?

Just find id by view and register click listener.
ImageButton notify = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.notify);
notify.setOnClick......

Comment: I did not used, it goes straight to the View.class when leaving the method

Comment: can you please post your layout xml with notify ImageButton.

Comment: Not yet, I can not find why not... I found the LogCat related to this error is this one: `07-28 11:17:08.595 1487-2742/? E/NotificationService: No Channel found for pkg=com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp, channelId=null, opPkg=com.example.carlosroldan.merlinminerapp, callingUid=10084, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10084, notification=Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=default defaults=0x1 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE) `